# sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl not found

Tags: java, ssl, kotlin, glassfish

When I try to use `okhttp` or `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` the following error occur

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Searching in the sun.security.ssl package, there is no SSLSessionImpl class

Im using Mac OS 10.13.3 (17D102)

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

And running my war on Glassfish 5.0

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'invoice-administration-api'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compileOnly group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.13.Final'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '2.26'
}

allOpen {
    annotation('javax.ejb.Stateless')
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: since this is the "correct answer" and Java 1.8.0-151 will potentialy lack security patches. I can't recommend to downgrade to a such an old Java version.

Please take a look at Payara project or new releases of Glassfish.

--

Try to downgrade the Java version to Java 1.8.0-151. It should work.

There's an issue in glassfish 5 with Java 8 161, there's an [issue](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22407) created, but no changes in nightly builds regarding the issue, I checked yesterday (19th march).

Comment: Thank you so much! Jdk 1.8.0_151 worked like a charm while trying to connect to MSSQL 2016 from glassfish 5.0 server

Comment: Worked for me.!

Comment: Since many of the JDK updates often involve security updates. You could be putting yourself at risk. Although this answer is correct I found Antoine's answer regarding removing sun folder from the specified jar to work without having to resort to downgrading JDK.

Answer (score 16):

The issue appears because Glassfish embeds native `sun.*` classes into `[glassfish5_home]/glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar`, so it conflicts with others classes included into `[JDK_HOME]/jre/lib/jsse.jar`

So edit the `grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar` (make a copy before) file and remove the sun folder.

Comment: Worked for me using JRE 1.8.0_191 and Payara 5.181

Comment: For those wondering how you can remove the classes from the jar. There is some similarities with jars and zip format. I used 7zip to delete the sun folder from the jar and restarted glassfish, worked like a charm.

Comment: Another note, there is also another issue which this solution resolves. With later versions of JDK and Glassfish 5 you will find exceptions that may be similar to java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.<init>(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/security/SecureRandom;Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Comment: @Antonie I have no words to thank you bro, really really thank you!!

Comment: This issue still exists with users on Glassfish 5.0 and Java 1.8.0_232.  But with Antoine's answer I was able to get passed the issue!

Comment: Thanks! Works for me as well, but in point of view - you cannot do it in production, right? or will it be a patched glassfish version?

Answer (score 5):

The above Error could result to this displaying in your browser:

```
The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.**
```

SOLUTION:

Download: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-npn-bootstrap/1.8.1/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.1.jar
and Replace your galssfish/payara  grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar.

```
mv grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.1.jar glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

The changes in the security ciphers in java 1.8.0_161 have broken the SSL function in the underlying Grizzly server of Glassfish 5,0. The last working java version was 1.8.0_152
 As of the moment of this writing i can confirm, that java 1.8.0_202 works with Glassfish 5.1 (now maintained by and downloadable from Eclipse.org)  The included grizzly-npn-bootstrap is ver 1.9.0. There is no need to delete or alter anything.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this frustrating issue and I did want to expand just a little on Antoine's answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/52479362/4722577 which worked for me.

As a note, I have Glassfish 5.0 and Java `openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)`

1. As mentioned by Antoine, I copied the `grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar` to another location as a backup.
2. I did the `jar -xvf grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar` to see the exact classes and folder locations in the jar. Which gave me the following output:

```
cduran@cduran-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ jar -xvf grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar 
 inflated: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  created: META-INF/
  created: META-INF/maven/
  created: META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.grizzly/
  created: META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-npn-bootstrap/
 inflated: META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-npn-bootstrap/pom.properties
 inflated: META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-npn-bootstrap/pom.xml
  created: org/
  created: org/glassfish/
  created: org/glassfish/grizzly/
  created: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/AlpnClientNegotiator.class
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/AlpnServerNegotiator.class
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/ClientSideNegotiator.class
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/NegotiationSupport.class
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/ServerSideNegotiator.class
  created: sun/
  created: sun/security/
  created: sun/security/ssl/
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/Alerts.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/AlpnExtension$Builder.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/AlpnExtension.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/ClientHandshaker$1.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/ClientHandshaker$2.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/ClientHandshaker.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/ExtensionType.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/GrizzlyNPN.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$1.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$CertificateRequest.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$CertificateVerify$1.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$CertificateVerify.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ClientHello.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$DH_ServerKeyExchange.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$DistinguishedName.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$Finished.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$HelloRequest.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$NextProtocol$Builder.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$NextProtocol.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$RSA_ServerKeyExchange.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ServerHello.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ServerHelloDone.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ServerKeyExchange.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/Handshaker$1.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/Handshaker$DelegatedTask.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/Handshaker.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/HelloExtensions.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/NextProtocolNegotiationExtension$Builder.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/NextProtocolNegotiationExtension.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/SSLEngineImpl.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/ServerHandshaker$1.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/ServerHandshaker$2.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/ServerHandshaker$3.class
 inflated: sun/security/ssl/ServerHandshaker.class
```

3. Observe that the jar file contains 3 folders in the root level: **META-INF**, **org**, and **sun**.  Again from Antoine's answer we want to remove the `sun` folder.
4. I don't know a command line way to recreate a jar by specifying a folder to remove, so I did this command where I recreate the `grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar` by just adding the **META-INF** and **org** folders: `jar -cvf grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar META-INF/* org/*`
5. Subsequently if I do the `jar -xvf grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar` command I get this output (notice no more **sun** folder listed):

```
cduran@cduran-VirtualBox:~/glassfish-5.0-web-profile/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed$ jar -xvf grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar 
  created: META-INF/
 inflated: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  created: META-INF/maven/
  created: META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.grizzly/
  created: META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-npn-bootstrap/
 inflated: META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-npn-bootstrap/pom.properties
 inflated: META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-npn-bootstrap/pom.xml
  created: org/glassfish/
  created: org/glassfish/grizzly/
  created: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/ClientSideNegotiator.class
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/ServerSideNegotiator.class
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/AlpnClientNegotiator.class
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/NegotiationSupport.class
 inflated: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/AlpnServerNegotiator.class
```

6. Restart your glassfish.

After this I no longer get that error message the OP posted above:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit more elegant is to use the existing fix done in the npn-grizzly jar:

```
mkdir -p scratch/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed && cd scratch
wget http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/nightly/glassfish-5.0.1-b02-12_03_2018.zip
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-npn-bootstrap/1.8.1/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.1.jar
mv grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.1.jar glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar
jar uvf glassfish-5.0.1-b02-12_03_2018.zip glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar 
echo "you have a patched archive for runnig with Java 8 patchlevel 191"
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had a deep dive in this issue just several days ago and found the root reason by reviewing JDK source code. I think you are using openjdk now.
This is a bug in openjdk up to 1.8.0_242.
The SSLSessionImpl is not instantiated when it is used in SSLSessionEngine. It is used as a static class, however it is only a final class.
The issue has been fixed in 1.8.0_252, so I recommend you to upgrade it to this version. Or switch to any build of Oracle jdk1.8.0, as there is no such bug in it.
Hope it helps.
Openjdk:
[SSLSessionEngine.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD1pH.png)
[SSLSessionImpl.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqGE8.png)
Oracle jdk:
[SSLSessionEngine.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX3t3.png)