# Why does Java Stripe API have Exception NoSuchMethodError for receiveChangeCipherSpec()?

Tags: java, stripe-payments, payara

I am using the Stripe Java library version 5.41.0 on void linux with Payara 5 and OpenJDK `[void@void ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_202"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b00, mixed mode)`

I am getting an exception for `receiveChangeCipherSpec` as follows:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.receiveChangeCipherSpec()V
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1150)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.makeURLConnectionRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:429)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.getStripeResponse(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:582)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.rawRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:500)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.staticRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:526)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:74)
    at com.stripe.net.APIResource.request(APIResource.java:186)
```

I thought it might be a lack of the unlimited security policy, but followed the procedure for installing that and I still have the exception as above.

The offending code is this line right now, although no API calls I am doing will work: `Customer.retrieve(stripeCustomerId)`

Would upgrading the Stripe library fix this, or am I missing a jar from Payara  or something?

Comment: `sun.security.ssl.Handshaker` Oracle purchased Sun in 2009. The classes in "sun.security" were still present in Java 1.7; but they're gone in 1.8. Upgrade Stripe to a version that supports Java 8.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: `sun.security.ssl` is in all j7-11; you may be thinking of the change from j5-6 where they were `com.sun.net.ssl.internal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is the same as here ([sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383650/sun-security-ssl-sslsessionimpl-not-found)). To summarize the problem is that exception NoSuchMethod is really erroneous, it should be more like `duplicate classes found`, since, to quote Antoine from that question:

Payara/`Glassfish embeds native sun.* classes into [glassfish5_home]/glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar, so it conflicts with others classes included into [JDK_HOME]/jre/lib/jsse.jar`

I used the solution from Antoine, which was to open `grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar` and delete the `sun` folder so that it no longer conflicts and loads the correct classes from `jsse.jar`.

On linux you can use Ark to open the jar and delete directly, and it appears that on Windows you can do the same thing with 7zip. Make a backup first in case you need to go back to the original jar in the future.

Comment: That makes sense; I had started to look at the source and there were definitely recent changes to these classes, including adding method `receiveChangeCipherSpec`, although I'm not good enough at mercurial to pin down exactly when. If your Payara jar contained a not-totally-up-to-date copy you would get this exception.