# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HelloExtension

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently working on a project which integrates PayPal payment into Java Maven web application using **NetBeans 8.2, jdk 1.8.0_311, and glassfish 5.0**.

There are **two **files,

**checkout.jsp :**

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Check Out</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table { border: 0; }
            table td { padding: 10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <h1>Check Out</h1>
            <br/>
            <form action="./authorize_payment" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product/Service:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product" value="Next iPhone" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub Total:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" value="100" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shipping:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="shipping" value="10" /></td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Tax:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="tax" value="10" /></td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Amount:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="total" value="120" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Checkout" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

and
**authorize_payment.java (servlet):**

```
package net.codejava.mavenproject1;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException;

@WebServlet("/authorize_payment")
public class authorize_payment extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public authorize_payment() {
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String product = request.getParameter("product");
    String subtotal = request.getParameter("subtotal");
    String shipping = request.getParameter("shipping");
    String tax = request.getParameter("tax");
    String total = request.getParameter("total");
     
    OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail(product, subtotal, shipping, tax, total);

    try {
        PaymentServices paymentServices = new PaymentServices();
        String approvalLink = paymentServices.authorizePayment(orderDetail);

        response.sendRedirect(approvalLink);
         
    } catch (PayPalRESTException ex) {
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}

}
```

When I clicked the "checkout" button on checkout.jsp, it showed :

**exception**

javax.servlet.ServletException: The HTTP Monitor server side component intercepted and rethrew an error while processing a JSP or servlet. Please see the stack trace under the root cause message below to identify the problem.

**root cause**

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension

**Full Stack Traces**

Severe:   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Severe:   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Severe:   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[net.codejava.mavenproject1.authorize_payment]: Servlet.service() for servlet net.codejava.mavenproject1.authorize_payment threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HelloExtension
at sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension.(SSLExtension.java:225)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLConfiguration.getEnabledExtensions(SSLConfiguration.java:380)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:562)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:509)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:115)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:250)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:587)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1354)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1329)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:111)
at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:65)
at com.paypal.base.rest.OAuthTokenCredential.generateAccessToken(OAuthTokenCredential.java:383)
at com.paypal.base.rest.OAuthTokenCredential.getAccessToken(OAuthTokenCredential.java:230)
at com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext.fetchAccessToken(APIContext.java:303)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:282)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:228)
at com.paypal.api.payments.Payment.create(Payment.java:149)
at net.codejava.mavenproject1.PaymentServices.authorizePayment(PaymentServices.java:35)
at net.codejava.mavenproject1.authorize_payment.doPost(authorize_payment.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[net.codejava.mavenproject1.authorize_payment]: Servlet.service() for servlet net.codejava.mavenproject1.authorize_payment threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension
at sun.security.ssl.SSLConfiguration.getEnabledExtensions(SSLConfiguration.java:380)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:562)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:509)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:115)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:250)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:587)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1354)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1329)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:111)
at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:65)
at com.paypal.base.rest.OAuthTokenCredential.generateAccessToken(OAuthTokenCredential.java:383)
at com.paypal.base.rest.OAuthTokenCredential.getAccessToken(OAuthTokenCredential.java:230)
at com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext.fetchAccessToken(APIContext.java:303)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:282)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:228)
at com.paypal.api.payments.Payment.create(Payment.java:149)
at net.codejava.mavenproject1.PaymentServices.authorizePayment(PaymentServices.java:35)
at net.codejava.mavenproject1.authorize_payment.doPost(authorize_payment.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I've tried to downgrade the jdk version to **jdk1.8.0_151, jdk1.8.0_181, jdk1.8.0_221, and jdk1.8.0_291**, but I still got the same error.
I've also tried to run the program using **glassfish server 5.1** but still no luck.
I've also tried the to **remove sun file in the grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar** as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383650/sun-security-ssl-sslsessionimpl-not-found), but unfortunately it didn't work.

I'm hoping someone can help me in identifying what the problem is, as I've been trying to solve it for nearly a week and it's driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is due to a webapp misconfiguration.  You need to read that link and take the action recommended to get properly functioning logging.

```
Severe: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Severe: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
Severe: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Then these come from different editions of Java 8

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HelloExtension
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension
```

The `HelloExtension` and `SSLExtension` classes are internal classes with the former replaced by the latter.

But note that the `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions probably don't mean that the class is missing.  They probably mean that the classes static initialization failed ... or that a class that the class depends on failed static initialization.

I would have expected there to be **other stacktraces** that correspond to the initialization failure.   Maybe they are missing because of the logging config problem.

---

It is not clear what the actual problem is, but it looks like something is failing during initialization of the SSL code.  One possibility is that there is a problem with your SSL settings.

My advice:

1. First fix the logging problem.
2. Next use the latest version of Java 8.  The chance that using an out-of-date Java 8 release will help is almost precisely zero.
3. Check any SSL settings that you are using in your web container.
4. Look for *other* stacktraces that explain *why* the following is happened:

   ```
    Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension
   ```

Comment: Hi, I've solved the logging problem and now there's another problem : 
`Severe:   [http-listener-1(5)] ERROR com.paypal.base.HttpConnection - Caught exception while handling error response
Severe:   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
 at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal`
Do you have any idea how to solve this? @Stephen C

Comment: It is not unusual for fixing one problem to reveal another one.   And when you get a new problem, the first thing you should do is look for a solution **yourself**.   Have you done that?